# Webscrap com Selenium - Como selecionar conteúdo de um item do menu drop-down com aspas no id

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Vi que tem uma pergunta parecida, mas a resposta ainda não me ajudou.

Preciso coletar dados do Banco Central. Para isso, preciso baixar os arquivos que estão em um drop down, um por vez.

Entretanto, estou com problemas já em selecionar apenas um.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver" # É preciso baixar o driver do navegador e por na pasta, devem ser a mesma versao
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww.bcb.gov.br%2Ffis%2Finfo%2Finstituicoes.asp%3Fidpai%3DINFCAD")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Cooperativas')).click()

select.select_by_visible_text('Maio/2019').click()

driver.quit()
```

Ele abre o chrome, entra no site, espera os 15 segundos para o site carregar, mas dá o seguinte erro:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Cooperativas"]"}

No site, tenho o select da seguinte maneira:

```
<select id="Cooperativas" "parametro"="" name="PARAMETRO"> Cooperativas
<option value="/fis/info/cad/cooperativas/202005COOPERATIVAS.zip">Maio/2020</option>
(outros options embaixo)
```

Tentei usar `find_element_by_xpath`, mas obtive os mesmo resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está ocorrendo pois toda a informação que você está tentando selecionar está dentro de um frame, tente da seguinte forma:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/legado?url=https:%2F%2Fwww.bcb.gov.br%2Ffis%2Finfo%2Finstituicoes.asp%3Fidpai%3DINFCAD')
sleep(3)
frame = driver.find_element_by_name('framelegado')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
sleep(2)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Cooperativas'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Maio/2019')
```

[image: Imagem Frame]

Comment: Perfeito! nos exemplos que vi, iam direto pro select, não usavam o frame antes. Obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, sempre que você tiver um popup, janela, alerta ou frame você precisa usar o switch_to() antes para conseguir interagir

Comment: Valeu pela dica!